# Why does a verbose person talk "nineteen to the dozen"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Though it is by no means common, I've heard this expression multiple times recently, and I'm wondering why it isn't "eighteen" to the dozen, or "thirteen", or "twenty".  Where did "nineteen" come from?

Comment: I quite like the fact that some smart-ass at Google programmed to look out for this one, just so they could have the calculator smugly tell us it's 2.21331492 × 10^15

Comment: They do have some techies there with a good sense of humour. Must be good bosses too, to let them get away with it!

Comment: I don't think it was this phrase in particular.  I just tried googling "twelve to the five" and got it calculated, too.

Comment: @GEdgar: Nobody says it that way, though.  This may be conspiracy-theorish, but I think they included that form just so "nineteen to the dozen" would be included. :)

Comment: It even calculates "nineteen to the baker's dozen" for you. :D

Comment: **fortnight to the score**  I think we are getting off topic here...

Comment: Daniel (re your comment), no, they included it because they include all powers. ["Three to the two"](//www.google.com/search?q=three+to+the+two) gets you 9. cc @GEdgar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't vouch for its veracity, but [here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20161217014143/http://online-english-lessons.eu:80/wordpress/2010/05/idiom-nineteen-to-the-dozen/) a site claiming the expression has its origins in the Cornish tin mining industry.

> Beam engines were introduced to reduce flooding in the mines, and they pumped out 19,000 gallons of water for every 12 bushels of coal needed to operate the engines – a much faster and more efficient way of pumping water than the hand pumps they replaced.